# Spring configuration : make a string attribute

Tags: java, spring, jndi

2 questions :

1. do you know a "best" way to use JNDI resources on spring
   configuration?
2. how can I transform the static attribut configPath to a "value" I can
   use in this 2 methods but also on other bean?

   ```
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.fdilogbox.report.serveur"})
   @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
   public class SpringConfig {

       public static final String JNDI_RESOURCES = "java:comp/env/report/config";
       public static String configPath;

       @PostConstruct
       public void initConfig() throws IllegalArgumentException {
           try {
               final JndiTemplate template = new JndiTemplate();
               configPath = (String) template.lookup(JNDI_RESOURCES);
               Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(configPath + "/log4j.xml");
           } catch (NamingException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to start logging, because non-file resource!", ex);
           }
       }

       @Bean
       public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
           try {
               final JndiTemplate template = new JndiTemplate();
               configPath = (String) template.lookup(JNDI_RESOURCES);
           } catch (NamingException ex) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("JNDI resource not found : " + JNDI_RESOURCES, ex);
           }
           PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ();
           Resource[] resources = new FileSystemResource[]{new FileSystemResource(configPath + "/application.properties")};
           pspc.setLocations(resources);
           pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
           return pspc;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Remove all of the JNDI stuff. Add a field of type `Environment` and use the `getProperty` method on that. It will automatically and transparently look into JNDI. If that is too late (as you seem to need that to locate some properties) put the code into an `ApplicationContextInitializer` do the lookup and loading of the properties in there.

Comment: I don't know how using Environment with JNDI. I don't need to locate this properties.

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of the documentation... The `Environment` by default does a lookup in JNDI... Work with the framework not around it.

Comment: I agree with you, it's why I ask question... I already use JNDI lookup with xml spring configuration file but not in class configuration.